# What segment is used by default in x86 indirect addressing?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a little confused as to exactly what segment is used when you have x86 assembly like the below (Intel syntax):

mov ax, [di]

I'm pretty certain it wouldn't be the code segment, I'm thinking either the data segment or the stack? (Or is the stack part of the data segment?)

Comment: Usually `DS` (the Data Segment).  The stack would be part of `SS` -- the Stack Segment.  `SP` and (I think) `BP` are the ones that default to `SS` while most other operations default to `DS`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Don't suppose you'd know what the direct addressing in this line would point to?
 call    far ptr 2480h:0DB0h

Comment: That would depend very strongly upon what mode you're programming in.  Real Mode?  Protected Mode?

Comment: bitRAKE reminded me of another oddity.  When you're doing the various string operations the source is usually `DS`:`SI` (data segment source index) and the destination is usually `ES`:`DI` (extra segment, destination index).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DS` is the default, except with `BP` indexing then `SS` is used. This exception is to ease the use of a stack frame (`ENTER`/`LEAVE` instructions). The string instructions have specific segment usage as well.

Comment: `SP` too indexes off the `SS`.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for this? I know it to be true, but can't pinpoint it in the IA-32 reference manual anywhere.

Comment: Besides being familiar with all the instructions, the best place to look is beginning of Vol.2, Chapter 2. Specifically, Table 2-1 thru 2-3. (At least in the manual I'm looking at.)

Comment: is there anyway that I can change the default data segment used?

Comment: With segment override prefixes.